# Testing equality of two X values in quadratic regression

Tags: regression, quadratic-form

So let's say we have a quadratic relationship between two variables, y and x. Graphically, it is U-shaped. However, there is also a linear component to it, such that the left curve is lower than the right curve (i.e. there is both a positive linear trend and a quadratic trend).

Now the question is the following: Let's say that I have a hypothesis that states that even though the relationship is curvilinear, the values for the leftmost values should be statistically different from the values for the rightmost value.. i.e. I want to perform a hypothesis test for the equality of specific values of the X variable.

I can't seem to wrap my head around how to do this. Any suggestions?

---

Here is a dummy data set created with Stata, that might be of use if anything is unclear:

---

```
set obs 10000 

gen x=rnormal(0,1)

gen y=30*x +20*x^2+100*rnormal(0,1) 

* put x on an ordinal scale, that runs from -5 to 5 

egen xx = cut(x), group(11)  
replace xx=xx-5

reg y c.xx##c.xx  

margins, at(xx=(-5/5))
marginsplot
```

---

This will show the curvilinear relationship... but how to I formally test the inequality between (say) the -5 and 5 values on the X variable?

Many thanks in advance!
AH

Comment: Do you mean if there is a difference in two y values at a given x?

Comment: No, if two different x values (on either side of the minimum value) have the same value on the y variable.

Answer (score 2):

You have $E(y|x) = f(x) = ax^2+bx+c$

You're interested in whether $f(5)-f(-5) \neq 0$

but $f(x)-f(-x) = 2x\cdot b$

and so - as long as $x\neq 0$, $\frac{f(x)-f(-x)}{2x}\neq 0 \implies f(x)-f(-x)\neq 0$.

Which is to say, simply test the linear coefficient - that's *identical* to testing $f(x)-f(-x)$ at any given $x=x_0$. Indeed, done correctly, it will give the same p-value, every time [a test for either is also a test for the other; more formally, they're *equivalent* -- i.e. at a given $\alpha$, they reject or fail to reject exactly the same cases - indeed their usual test statistics would be the same if both were standardized].

So if $b$ is significantly different from zero, so is $f(5)-f(-5)$.

Answer (score 1):

This can be done with adjacent reverse contrast operators:

```
reg y c.xx##c.xx  
margins, at(xx=(-5 5 -4 4 -3 3 -2 2 -1 1)) contrast(atcontrast(ar(2(2)10)._at) wald)
```